# ERROR TypeError: this.data is not a function at

Tags: angular, api, typescript

i try to pass the variable of my alpha2code trough a another component so when i click on the row of my table it should show only the data according to the alpha2code.

this is the function when i click on a specific row of the table

```
onRowClicked(row) {
console.log('Row clicked: ', row);
console.log(row.alpha2Code);
this.data(row.alpha2Code);
 location.href="/country";
}
```

this is setter to set the alpha2code from that row to the value in my service

```
set data(value: any) {
this.getservice.alpha2Code = value;
}
```

my service :

```
export class GetCountries {
alpha2Code : any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
public GetAllStationCountries(){
return this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
   }
}
```

in my child component i try to bind that value from my parent to my child here,that has been set before :

```
public get data():any {
return this.getservice.alpha2Code;  
}
```

if i do something completely wrong , tell me. My first purpose was just to pass data from my parent component to my child so i can do i get from the country API with paramter the alpha2code so i make a dashboard with more detailed information about the country you just clicked on in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting error on line with code `this.data(row.alpha2Code);` . Replace this line with `this.data = row.alpha2Code;` . Hope this will fix this error. As data is not a function its an input variable configured using set method.